# Neural Network Backpropagation Algorithm Implementation

Tags: matlab, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I implemented a Neural Network Back propagation Algorithm in MATLAB, however is is not training correctly. The training data is a matrix `X = [x1, x2]`, dimension `2 x 200` and I have a target matrix `T = [target1, target2]`, dimension `2 x 200`. The first 100 columns in T can be `[1; -1]` for class 1, and the second 100 columns in T can be `[-1; 1]` for class 2.

```
theta = 0.1; % criterion to stop
eta = 0.1; % step size
Nh = 10;  % number of hidden nodes
```

For some reason the total training error is always 1.000, it never goes close to the `theta`, so it runs forever.

I used the following formulas:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The total training error:
[image]

The code is well documented below. I would appreciate any help.

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

%%('---------------------')
%%('Generating dummy data')
%%('---------------------')
d11 = [2;2]*ones(1,70)+2.*randn(2,70);
d12 = [-2;-2]*ones(1,30)+randn(2,30);
d1 = [d11,d12];

d21 = [3;-3]*ones(1,50)+randn([2,50]);
d22 = [-3;3]*ones(1,50)+randn([2,50]);
d2 = [d21,d22];

hw5_1 = d1;
hw5_2 = d2;

save hw5.mat hw5_1 hw5_2

x1 = hw5_1;
x2 = hw5_2;

% step 1: Construct training data matrix X=[x1,x2], dimension 2x200
training_data = [x1, x2];

% step 2: Construct target matrix T=[target1, target2], dimension 2x200
target1 = repmat([1; -1], 1, 100);  % class 1
target2 = repmat([-1; 1], 1, 100);  % class 2
T = [target1, target2];

% step 3: normalize training data
training_data = training_data - mean(training_data(:));
training_data = training_data / std(training_data(:));

% step 4: specify parameters
theta = 0.1; % criterion to stop 
eta   = 0.1; % step size 
Nh    = 10;  % number of hidden nodes, actual hidden nodes should be 11 (including a biase)
Ni    = 2;   % dimension of input vector = number of input nodes, actual input nodes should be 3 (including a biase)
No    = 2;   % number of class = number of out nodes

% step 5: Initialize the weights 
a = -1/sqrt(No);
b = +1/sqrt(No);
inputLayerToHiddenLayerWeight  = (b-a).*rand(Ni, Nh) + a
hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight = (b-a).*rand(Nh, No) + a

J = inf;

p = 1;

% activation function 
% f(net) = a*tanh(b*net), 
% f'(net) = a*b*sech2(b*net)
a = 1.716;
b = 2/3;

while J > theta

    % step 6: randomly choose one training sample vector from X, 
    % together with its target vector
    k = randi([1, size(training_data, 2)]);
    input_X = training_data(:,k);
    input_T = T(:,k);

    % step 7: Calculate net_j values for hidden nodes in layer 1 
    % hidden layer output before activation function applied
    netj = inputLayerToHiddenLayerWeight' * input_X;

    % step 8: Calculate hidden node output Y using activation function
    % apply activation function to hidden layer neurons
    Y = a*tanh(b*netj);

    % step 9: Calculate net_k values for output nodes in layer 2
    % output later output before activation function applied
    netk = hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight' * Y;

    % step 10: Calculate output node output Z using the activation function
    % apply activation function to the output layer neurons
    Z = a*tanh(b*netk);

    % step 11: Calculate sensitivity delta_k = (target - Z) * f'(Z) 
    % find the error between the expected_output and the neuron output
    % we got using the weights
    % delta_k = (expected - output) * activation(output)
    delta_k = [];
    for i=1:size(Z)
        yi = Z(i,:);
        expected_output = input_T(i,:);
        delta_k = [delta_k; (expected_output - yi) ...
                                * a*b*(sech(b*yi)).^2];
    end

    % step 12: Calculate sensitivity 
    % delta_j = Sum_k(delta_k * hidden-to-out weights) * f'(net_j)
    % error = (weight_k * error_j) * activation(output)
    delta_j = [];
    for j=1:size(Y)
        yi = Y(j,:);
        error = 0;
        for k=1:size(delta_k)
            error = error + delta_k(k,:)*hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight(j, k);
        end
        delta_j = [delta_j; error * (a*b*(sech(b*yi)).^2)];
    end

    % step 13: update weights

    %2x10
    inputLayerToHiddenLayerWeight = [];
    for i=1:size(input_X)
        xi = input_X(i,:);
        wji = [];
        for j=1:size(delta_j)
            wji = [wji, eta * xi * delta_j(j,:)];
        end
        inputLayerToHiddenLayerWeight = [inputLayerToHiddenLayerWeight; wji];
    end

    inputLayerToHiddenLayerWeight

    %10x2
    hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight = [];
    for j=1:size(Y)
        yi = Y(j,:);
        wjk = [];
        for k=1:size(delta_k)
            wjk = [wjk, eta * delta_k(k,:) * yi];
        end
        hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight = [hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight; wjk];
    end

    hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight

    % Mean Square Error
    J = 0;
    for j=1:size(training_data, 2)
        X = training_data(:,j);
        t = T(:,j);
        netj = inputLayerToHiddenLayerWeight' * X;
        Y = a*tanh(b*netj);
        netk = hiddenLayerToOutputLayerWeight' * Y;
        Z = a*tanh(b*netk);
        J = J + immse(t, Z);
    end

    J = J/size(training_data, 2)

    p = p + 1;
    if p == 4
        break;
    end
end

% testing neural network using the inputs
test_data = [[2; -2], [-3; -3], [-2; 5], [3; -4]];

for i=1:size(test_data, 2)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Weight decay isn't essential for Neural Network training.

What I did notice was that your feature normalization wasn't correct.

The correct algorthim for scaling data to the range of 0 to 1 is

(max - x) / (max - min)

Note: you apply this for every element within the array (or vector). Data inputs for NN need to be within the range of [0,1]. (Technically they can be a little bit outside of that ~[-3,3] but values furthur from 0 make training difficult)

edit*

I am unaware of this activation function

```
a = 1.716;
b = 2/3;
% f(net) = a*tanh(b*net), 
% f'(net) = a*b*sech2(b*net)
```

It sems like a variation on tanh. 
Could you elaborate what it is?

If you're net still doesn't work give me an update and I'll look at your code more closely.

Comment: normalization to 0 mean and std 1 (which is used in OP code) is actually a better method than the one you are proposing (which is biased towards outliers)

Comment: Its generally assumed that you don't have any blatant outliers in your training set. Your method is still biased towards outliers (though a bit more resilient). Generally its nonsensical to train a predictive model with outliers (as they're aren't reflective of the majority you are trying to predict)

Yours also puts data into the range of -1,1 which is somewhat atypical from standard practice.

Comment: this is not "my" method but rather a standard in statistical analysis. It makes does not put data into [-1,1], it simply makes the (diagonal) empirical covariance become identity and puts expected value in 0, nothing else. Especially the second property has nice properties, which is lost if one just squashes values to [0,1] - but of course everything depends on the application/problem. None of this approaches should lead to the failure described in the question. In terms of your question to the OP - 1.716 and 2/3 are old constants (from 90s), that were considered a well adjusted ones.

Comment: Dataset = [1, 2, 3] 
mean = 2 
std (Sample) = 1

x = 1,

(1 - 2)/1 = - 1

Comment: Also yes, I know you didn't create z score.